# How to nest two many-to-many fields in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a table that relates two tables, table Author and table Book.

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| ID | Author(FK) | Book (FK) |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 |         20 |        12 |
|  2 |         20 |        35 |
|  3 |         20 |        70 |
|  4 |         25 |        15 |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

I am using a serializer and my output looks like this:

```
{
  "1": {
    "Author": "20",
    "Book": "12"
  },
  "2": {
    "Author": "20",
    "Book": "35"
  },
  "3": {
    "Author": "20",
    "Book": "70"
  },
  "4": {
    "Author": "25",
    "Book": "15"
  },
}
```

The desired output would be like this:

```
[
  {
    "author": 20,
    "books": [
      12,
      35,
      70
    ]
  },
  {
    "author": 25,
    "books": [
      15
    ]
  }
]
```

This is my serializer:

```
class AuthorBooksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AuthorBooks
        fields = '__all__'
```

What should I do to merge all the books of an author into one array?

Comment: please, share your models

Comment: Check out [this in the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)

Answer (score 0):

Using [DRF's PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield), you can improve your `AuthorBooksSerializer` like so:

```py
from .models import Book, Author, AuthorBooks

class AuthorBooksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, queryset=Author.objects.all())
    books = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, queryset=Book.objects.all())
    
    class Meta:
        model = AuthorBooks
        fields = '__all__'
```

---

#### Bonus

Instead of defining a seperate model `AuthorBooks` you can just use the [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) attribute on your `Book` model to achieve SQL's `Many to One relationship`, for example,

```py
from django.db import models
class Book(models.Model):
   # ...snip...
   author = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name="books", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and then you can make queries like:

```py
Book.objects.get(1).author # related author instance
Author.objects.get(1).books # list of books
```